# Use list filter value when adding new items to list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In a webpart page I got a list that is filtered on a value given from another webpart.

When adding an item to that list (from this webpart page); is there a way to preset the column the list is filtered on to be the same as the filter value?

Thanks.

Ivar

Answer (score 0):

this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/10/29/setting-sharepoint-form-fields-using-query-string-variables-without-using.aspx) describes how to pre-fill field based on a query string variable. It can be useful for you, and if you add some modification to this solution your problem should be solved. The thing is that when you come to the part where you create the parameter for the "New item form" web part, you'll not specify to be a query string parameter. Instead it should be of type "None", and after that when you make the connections between the webparts you'll connect them in a way that they pass parameters to each other, not filters. I had some similar problem recently and made it work out in this way.